# recode various variables in R under conditions

Tags: r

I am a novice in R and trying to recode more than one variable at one time. All variables have similar restrictions:
I am happy about any helpful commments.

```
#  actually real life data
Bed <- rep(c("1", "2"),10) 
reported <- rep(c("yes", "no"), 10)
x <- c(100:110) #in real life a few missings and more variable
var1 <- x 
var2 <- x
data <- data.frame(Bed, reported, var1, var2)
#etc.

#restrictions
reported <- rep(c("yes","no"), each=4) 
Bed <- rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), each=2)
mtrx <- matrix( , nrow(data),160)
data_new <- data.frame(mtrx) 

#this is the part that does not work!
for (i in 1:20){ 
 for (j in 1:8)
  data_new[,i][(data$reported==reported[2*j]) & (data$Bed==Bed[j])] <- data[,(i+6)] [(data$reported==reported[2*j]) & (data$Bed==Bed[j])] 
}
```

--> data includes 20 variables which shall be recoded into data_new under conditions

- if the conditions are not true the value is NA (so we get a lot of NAs)
- the new dataset 20 (variables) x 2 (reported condition) x 4 (Bed condition) new variables

Comment: We don't have `data` and it would be helpful if you would reduce your example to smaller one and add the desired output accompanied with explanations.

Comment: Thank you David for your comments. I've included the information in the original post now.

Comment: It looks like your double loop can be handled with `?ifelse`.

Comment: @Zelazny: can you give me a hint where to incorporate "ifelse" in the script?